# I <went to/have been> to Australia when I was a student

Tags: grammar

which one is grammatically correct? I'm a total beginner, please help me to understand past tense and present perfect

Answer (score 2):

It's more about usage than grammatical correctness. We would say

> I went to Australia when I was a student.

...but we could also say

> Yes, I have been to Australia. It was when I was a student.

The present perfect indicates that you have had that experience at some time in the past, rather than mentioning a particular occasion. See https://www.englishpage.com/verbpage/presentperfect.html